# How to run an If statement inside For statement to show only specific rows of a data set

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am running the for loop below to create a table of data (Product Name, Ask Price, Bid Price, ID). It works perfect with the data that I have but my data is 100s of rows long and we only need to display 25 items from it. I am looking for a way to show just the rows that match the ID number that I want to display (my programming skills are really rusty).

Working code to show all rows of data:

```
           for(var i=0; i<priceDatas.length; i++){
                var bidprice = "";
                var askprice = "";
                
               
                if(priceDatas[i]["bidPrice"]){
                  bidprice = priceDatas[i]["bidPrice"] - (priceDatas[i]["bidPrice"] * 1.5 / 100);
                  bidprice = bidprice.toFixed(2);
                  bidprice = "$" + bidprice;
                } else if(priceDatas[i]["Bid %"]){
                  bidprice = priceDatas[i]["Bid %"] - (priceDatas[i]["Bid %"] * 1.5 / 100);
                  bidprice = bidprice.toFixed(2);
                  bidprice = bidprice + "%";
                }
                
                if(priceDatas[i]["askPrice"]){
                  askprice = priceDatas[i]["askPrice"] + (priceDatas[i]["askPrice"] * 1.5 / 100);
                  askprice = askprice.toFixed(2);
                  askprice = "$" + askprice;
                } else if(priceDatas[i]["Ask %"]){
                  askprice = priceDatas[i]["Ask %"] + (priceDatas[i]["Ask %"] * 1.5 / 100);
                  askprice = askprice.toFixed(2);
                  askprice = askprice + "%";
                }
                
                
                var column = "<tr>";
                column = column + "<td>" + priceDatas[i]["Display Name"] + "</td>" + "<td>" + `${bidprice? bidprice :"-"}` + "</td>" + "<td>" + `${askprice? askprice :"-"}` + "</td>" + "<td>" + priceDatas[i]["id"] + "</td>";
                column = column + "</tr>";
                table = table + column;
                
              }
              
            document.getElementById("price_table").innerHTML = "<tr class='header-table'><td>Product</td><td>Bid</td><td>Ask</td><td>ID</td>" + table + "</tr>";
```

I want to add a set of IDs to only show specific items on the table instead of the entire table. I thought I could do something like this:

```
if(priceDatas[i]["id"] = "3081" || "54" || "56" ) { }
```

wrapped around the code above but it doesn't matter where I put it in the for loop, it just changes what is displayed in the ID column. I have tried with `===` and it doesn't work either.

How can I say if the ID is one of the numbers in my list show only those `column` in my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `filter` function of `Array` to filter your `priceDatas`, and `forEach` instead of `for`

code:

```js
priceDatas.filter(row => ["3081", "54", "56"].includes(row["id"])).forEach(row => {
    let bidprice = "";
    let askprice = "";


    if (row["bidPrice"]) {
        bidprice = row["bidPrice"] - (row["bidPrice"] * 1.5 / 100);
        bidprice = bidprice.toFixed(2);
        bidprice = "$" + bidprice;
    } else if (row["Bid %"]) {
        bidprice = row["Bid %"] - (row["Bid %"] * 1.5 / 100);
        bidprice = bidprice.toFixed(2);
        bidprice = bidprice + "%";
    }

    if (row["askPrice"]) {
        askprice = row["askPrice"] + (row["askPrice"] * 1.5 / 100);
        askprice = askprice.toFixed(2);
        askprice = "$" + askprice;
    } else if (row["Ask %"]) {
        askprice = row["Ask %"] + (row["Ask %"] * 1.5 / 100);
        askprice = askprice.toFixed(2);
        askprice = askprice + "%";
    }


    let column = "<tr>";
    column = column + "<td>" + row["Display Name"] + "</td>" + "<td>" + `${bidprice ? bidprice : "-"}` + "</td>" + "<td>" + `${askprice ? askprice : "-"}` + "</td>" + "<td>" + row["id"] + "</td>";
    column = column + "</tr>";
    table = table + column;
})
```